# How long would the reed be in Matthew 27:48?

Tags: matthew, cross

[Matthew 27:48](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/mat/27/48/s_956048)

> Immediately one of them ran and took a sponge, filled it with sour
> wine and put it on a reed, and offered it to Him to drink. (NKJV)

When Jesus was crucified and cried out, the above verse tells us of one person's response. The fact that he attached the sponge to a reed tells me that Jesus was not crucified low to the ground like some depictions we see, but much higher up. If the reed was 3 feet, then the person would lift his arm up above his head about a foot, and the reed would reach another 3 feet. So the Son of God's head could be about 9-10 feet from the ground, depending on the height of the man holding the reed.

**How long would a reed like that be?** Is my guess reasonable?

Comment: It is also possible that the reed wasn't used to gain height. Having a little extra reach would allow them hold it at an angle so the sour wine didn't drip all over them. It might also allow them to hold it there for longer while Jesus drank, or even just because a wet floppy sponge might be difficult to maintain a grasp on above your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel account at John 19:29 calls this a "hyssop" branch or stalk.

In the topic of "[Hyssop](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002122#h=6)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures*, we get a description of this plant:

> The hyssop mentioned in connection with Jesus Christ’s impalement ([John 19:29](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002122/6/0)) is thought by some to refer to durra, or Indian millet, a variety of common sorghum (*Sorghum vulgare*). It is a tall, small-grained plant with long, broad leaves. Since this plant commonly attains a height of at least 1.8 m (6 ft) in Palestine, it could have provided a stalk, or “reed,” of sufficient length to convey the sponge of sour wine to Jesus’ mouth. ([Matthew 27:48;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002122/7/0) [Mark 15:36](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002122/7/1))

So the plant could provide a "reed" of three feet or even up to six feet which, using the reasoning of the original question, could place Jesus' head up to 13 feet above the ground.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 3):

The word in the [original Greek](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/27-48.htm) is  κάλαμος [Strong 2563](https://biblehub.com/greek/2563.htm) which is also the word for the 'reed' with which soldiers struck Jesus' head and also the measuring 'rod' in Revelation and also the 'pen' which John used to write with.

The word could be translated 'stick' - a writing-stick, a measuring-stick, or a walking-stick.

The length (and breadth) of the stick will vary dependent on context and application.

It is not possible to determine, from the text of scripture, what length the 'stick' would be which was used to hoist up the sponge to Jesus' lips as he was crucified.

Any attempt to be categoric about this, is simply supposition.

Where scripture does not supply detail, guess-work is inadvisable because, often, where practical, technical and natural detail are missing, it is deliberate ; in order to draw our attention away from such matters and to prompt us with spiritual allusion . . .

. . . .  as may be the case here for 'hyssop' (from John's account) has a depth of meaning in relation to sacrifice in the Old Testament and in the quotation in the Psalms :

> ... purge me with hyssop and I shall be clean ... [Psalm 51:7 KJV]